# Why does Haskell want this function's argument to have the type classes (RealFrac x, Integral x) when it only needs to be Integral x?

Tags: haskell, show, integral

I'm trying to write some code that does a complete factorization of an integer by trial division. This code seems like it ought to work:

```
findAFact :: Integral x => x -> x
findAFact x = searchInts [2, 3..] x where
    searchInts (int:ints) div
        | div `mod` int == 0 = int
        | otherwise          = searchInts ints div

completeFacts :: Integral x => x -> [x]
completeFacts x = tryForFact [] x where
    tryForFact fs x = if x == 1
                      then fs
                      else let fact = findAFact x
                           in tryForFact (fact:fs) (floor ((fromIntegral x) / fact))
```

but if I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (RealFrac x) arising from a use of 'tryForFact'
from the context (Integral x)
  bound by the type signature for
             completeFacts :: Integral x => x -> [x]
  at 5.hs:26:18-39
Possible fix:
  add (RealFrac x) to the context of
    the type signature for completeFacts :: Integral x => x -> [x]
In the expression: tryForFact [] x
In an equation for 'completeFacts':
    completeFacts x
      = tryForFact [] x
      where
          tryForFact fs x
            = if x == 1 then
                  fs
              else
                  let ... in tryForFact (fact : fs) (floor ((fromIntegral x) / fact))
```

If I remove the type signature from `completeFacts` and try loading it into GHCI, the interpreter loads the file and supplies the type signature `(RealFrac x, Integral x ) => x -> [x]` for `completeFacts`, but then complains when I try to use `completeFacts` that there's no way to `show` it because its type is ambiguous in the context of `show`. That makes sense to me because it seems like there would be a clear way to display x as a `RealFrac` *or* an `Integral`, but not both.

This seems to be the offending code:

```
...
in tryForFact (fact:fs) (floor ((fromIntegral x) / fact))
```

I'm confused because I'd imagine passing x through `fromIntegral` and then passing the result of the division into `floor` would give me an `Integral` back. I don't see why Haskell still thinks x also needs to have the type class `RealFrac`. Why does Haskell insist on this, and how can I rewrite `completeFacts` so that x can just be an `Integral`?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you used `/`.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it with `div` and got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you didn't convert `fact` to a `RealFrac` before doing division:

```
in tryForFact (fact:fs) (floor (fromIntegral x / fromIntegral fact))
```

You've said that `fact = findAFact x`, which has type `Integral x => x`, but you're using it in a division with `/`, so it thinks it needs to satisfy both `Integral` and `RealFrac`.

What would actually be better is to just use `div` instead (I've also cleaned up the code a little bit so that it's easier to read and you aren't shadowing an existing binding for `x`):

```
completeFacts :: Integral x => x -> [x]
completeFacts x = tryForFact [] x
    where
        tryForFact fs 1 = fs
        tryForFact fs y = let fact = findAFact y
                          in tryForFact (fact:fs) (y `div` fact)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks; I needed to just simplify `floor ((fromIntegral x) / fact)` down to `x \`div\` fact` and get rid of all the surrounding cruft.

Comment: @ZackAnderson Or that.  I just showed how you can leave that in, if you really want to use that way.  `div` would be much simpler, though, and probably a lot faster.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see what you were initially saying now—`fact` had the same constraints as `x` and I was missing that, which is why using `fromIntegral` twice or not using it at all and just using `div` both worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ZackAnderson, actually, if you know the numbers are positive (which seems to be the case here), you can get better performance using `quot` and `rem` (or `quotRem`) rather than `div` and `mod`.

Answer (score 1):

The `floor` and `/` functions are what tripped you up.

```
(floor ((fromIntegral x) / fact))
```

Try using `div` instead.

```
fromIntegral x `div` fact
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I tried this and I'm still getting the same result.